# Why do all my blocks increase when one of them becomes bigger?

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have three blocks that consist of parent and child blocks. So, why do all my blocks increase when one of them becomes bigger? How can I get rid of this?

I mean, I add my text to the first block. Why doesn't only my first block become bigger? Why does it about all blocks?

You can see my example below

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.groups_line {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1565px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.line {
    width: 520px;
    min-height: fit-content;
    margin-right: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.line:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.first_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/X7K9PsbD/13-2x.png);
}

.second_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/hGvxfg7H/kaboompics-com-Woman-preparing-a-lunch-on-the-kitchen-table.png);
}

.third_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/s2GXk2WD/photo-1453822858805-7c095c06011e.png);
}

.wrapper_foot {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 18px 15px 10px 15px;
}

.heading_block {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #b59f5b;
    margin: 20px 10px 15px 10px;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.data {
    opacity: 0.54;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.number {
    opacity: 0.54;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline;
}

.fa-comment {
    color: #b59f5b;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Font Awesome";
}

.border {
    width: 465px;
    min-height: 135px;
    border: 3px solid #b59f5b;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@400;500;600&family=Open+Sans:wght@600;700&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="groups_line">
            <div class="first_group line">
                <div class="first-group-line border">
                    <p class="group_line heading_block">beauty   health  life</p>
                    <p class="group_line text">FROM GRAPEFRUIT TO LEMONS TO ORANGES, CITRUS DOES YOU GOOD! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis nemo ducimus alias necessitatibus doloribus? Harum libero reiciendis ipsam vitae, corrupti quos molestias quis, provident iste nam officia. Odio, voluptatum saepe!</p>
                    <div class="wrapper_foot">
                        <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                        <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                            <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                            <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="second_group line">
            <div class="second-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading_block">health</p>
                <p class="group_line text">5 Tips To Supercharge Your 
Motivation</p>
                <div class="wrapper_foot">
                    <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                    <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                        <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_group line">
            <div class="third-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading_block">Beauty</p>
                <p class="group_line text">To Keep Makeup Looking Fresh Take A Powder</p>
                <div class="wrapper_foot">
                    <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                    <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                        <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have set the `flex` display on `.line` class.

Remove `display: flex; justify-content: center` on `.lines` class and to put the child element in the center of `lines` div,

pls add `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` to `borders` class.

I have attached the changes.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.groups_line {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1565px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.line {
    width: 520px;
    min-height: fit-content;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.line:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.first_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/X7K9PsbD/13-2x.png);
}

.second_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/hGvxfg7H/kaboompics-com-Woman-preparing-a-lunch-on-the-kitchen-table.png);
}

.third_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/s2GXk2WD/photo-1453822858805-7c095c06011e.png);
}

.wrapper_foot {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 18px 15px 10px 15px;
}

.heading_block {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #b59f5b;
    margin: 20px 10px 15px 10px;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.data {
    opacity: 0.54;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.number {
    opacity: 0.54;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline;
}

.fa-comment {
    color: #b59f5b;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Font Awesome";
}

.border {
    width: 465px;
    min-height: 135px;
    border: 3px solid #b59f5b;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@400;500;600&family=Open+Sans:wght@600;700&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="groups_line">
            <div class="first_group line">
                <div class="first-group-line border">
                    <p class="group_line heading_block">beauty   health  life</p>
                    <p class="group_line text">FROM GRAPEFRUIT TO LEMONS TO ORANGES, CITRUS DOES YOU GOOD! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis nemo ducimus alias necessitatibus doloribus? Harum libero reiciendis ipsam vitae, corrupti quos molestias quis, provident iste nam officia. Odio, voluptatum saepe!</p>
                    <div class="wrapper_foot">
                        <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                        <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                            <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                            <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="second_group line">
            <div class="second-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading_block">health</p>
                <p class="group_line text">5 Tips To Supercharge Your 
Motivation</p>
                <div class="wrapper_foot">
                    <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                    <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                        <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_group line">
            <div class="third-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading_block">Beauty</p>
                <p class="group_line text">To Keep Makeup Looking Fresh Take A Powder</p>
                <div class="wrapper_foot">
                    <p class="group-line data"> June 14, 2015</p>
                    <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                        <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```